# extract information from string with specific format

Tags: java, string

everyone.I have a question about extracting information from a string with specific structure.

For example, I have a string with the structure:

BLOCK block_name INPUT=input1 input2 ... OUTPUT=output1 output2 ...

The upper case words are fixed and lower case words can be changed.
 I would like to extract the block_name, all the inputs and outputs. I would like to know what is the easiest way to do this? I know I can use StringTokenizer to go through all the words in the string, but  the code will be kind of complicated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: StringTokenizer seems like a good option. I don't see how messy it could get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could use String-function "indexof" to get the index of the "INPUT" (endindex of block_name would then be i-1) and then get the name with String.substring(6, endindex)

Comment: what if the blockname contains "INPUT"?

Comment: Well, that is indeed a problem :) Check for "INPUT=" perhaps? You could of course store the block_names with start- and end-characters to avoid misinterpretation?

Comment: Yes,  Check for "INPUT=" is a good idea, thanks! What do you mean by "You could of course store the block_names with start- and end-characters to avoid misinterpretation? "

Comment: If the block-name and input1 input2... can be of any format and contain any characters, then indeed it is hard to recognize where your names begins and ends. if spaces are only allowed between words, then you can split the string between " " and take the second entity

Comment: Well if your block_name can contain whitespaces, f.e. "Bill Gates", then you can not know where a block begins and ends. then you can use some special characters to mark the names, f.e. %Bill Gates%

Comment: Good idea. And just want to double check if I use the indexof("INPUT="), the endindex of block_name should be i-2 not i-1 right?

Comment: I think you need i-1 because in String.substring(i, j) i is inclusive and j is exclusive. For example "Bill Gates".substring(1,3) would return "il"

Comment: If I use the indexof("INPUT="), I won't have problem of that inside the block_name has space.

Comment: Well no, but it is still possible that some idiot would name a block "BLOCKINPUT=3" in worst case :P

Comment: HAHAHA~ Yes, you are right, but I will first ignore these~ Thank you for your help!